# For Loop is starting at the wrong number

Tags: javascript, for-loop

For some reason the second `for` loop is starting at 1. I do realize that first `for` loop `i` starts at one. That's is meant to be. However, even though `j` `for` loop says to start at 0, it starts at 1 anyways.

```
var findWinners = function (playersRay) {
    var players = playersRay;
    var results = new Array();

    //getdealers dealers hand and info
    var dealerHand = players[0]
    var dealerScore = dealerHand.getScore()
    var dealerBust = dealerScore > 21 ? true : false;

    //loops through all players; skips dealer (array position 0)
    var numPlayers = players.length;
    for (var i=1; i<numPlayers; i++) {
            //loops through all the players hands.
            //player might have more than 1 hand if he splits his cards
        var player = players[i];
        var numHands = player.length;
        results[i] = new Array();

        for (var j=0; j<numHands; j++)
            var handScore = player[j].getScore();

            if (handScore > 21) {
                results[i][j] = false;              
            }
            else if (dealerScore > 21) {
                results[i][j] = true;
            }
            else if (handScore > dealerScore) {
                results[i][j] = true;
            }
            else {
                results[i][j] = false;
            }
    }
    return results;
}
```

It returns this: `[undefined, [undefined, true]]`

It should return this: `[undefined, [true]]`

Just in case you want to know. A sample `playersRay` is:  `[Object, [Object]]`
*The object has information about the dealer's or player's blackjack hand.*

Link to full code: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxvwY0fUFc3aMTdTOXU0b0ttamM

Comment: It's not possible for that loop to be starting at 1. Look elsewhere for your problem.

Comment: That's my point exactly. I tested this by using `console.log(j)` within the 2nd `for` loop. It only output `1`. There wasn't a `0` before it either.

Comment: Make a smaller (reproducible) example where the problem still exists. You'll either find the bug yourself ór have something to show us which we can debug - this code here is not independant enough to run.

Comment: I agree with konerak, what does the getScore function do?,watch out for j=value (withouth var j before) since it can change your j value.

Comment: @SgtOJ How are you calling the function?

Comment: Add link to full code. It still in the works, so there is no GUI yet. Everything prints to console and make use of `confirm` popups.

Comment: Why don't you have `{}` around the inner `for`? Not sure if that will fix the issue, but it sure seems odd.

Comment: @SgtOJ `var suit = suit` and `var number = number;` is redundant..Why do you have it?

Comment: Actually, yeah, I think that's your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/MMQD8/

Comment: @JaredFarrish If you post your comment as a question, I will select it as the right answer. That's what the problem was. I have no idea why there wasn't one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, when you omit the curly braces around a statement, it only runs the first line. The behavior appears to omit only the first index, when I suspect there's only two. So if you add some more to iterate, you should notice it's actually just running the *last* index.

For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    console.log('First line: ', i);

    console.log('Second line: ', i);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MMQD8/

Gives:

```
First line: 0
First line: 1
First line: 2
First line: 3
First line: 4
First line: 5
First line: 6
First line: 7
First line: 8
First line: 9
Second line: 10
```

MDN [explains it thusly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

> **statement**
>
> A statement that is executed as long as the condition 
>   evaluates to true. To execute multiple statements within the loop, use a block
>   statement ({ ... }) to group those statements.